# NSHTTPCookie: expiresDate is always null

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, nshttpcookie

I'm creating a cookie using NSHTTPCookie. But when I create the expiration date is getting converted to creation date. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *cProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

   [cProperties setObject:@"31 May 2016 17:04:14 GMT" forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:];
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
```

Per console output:

```
    <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"myCookie" 
 expiresDate:(null) created:2016-05-31 16:32:37 +0000 
sessionOnly:TRUE  path:"/" isSecure:TRUE>
```

Any of you knows why my expiresDate is getting switch with created date ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you by chance find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing the properties to the cookie.  You want:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cProperties];
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also it's probably easier to set the expires date/time using an `NSDate` object instead of an `NSString`.

Comment: I believe he missed to write it when giving the example if not his code wouldn't work would it?

Answer (score 0):

NSHTTPCookieExpires is expecting NSDate as a value type, based on [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSHTTPCookie/expiresDate)
So you have to use NSDate type value such as `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60]` to set NSHTTPCookieExpires key

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/HTTP_Cookie_Attribute_Keys) says it accepts either `NSDate` or `NSString` when set via the properties.  I agree that using `NSDate` is better though.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, you are right. NSString is acceptable. I think the problem is the format of the NSString, it needs to be something like "2016-06-01 23:50:39 +0000", follow the NSDate or look at the value for "created"